# jQuery XML Portfolio Gallery

Tags: jquery, xml, gallery, portfolio

jQuery XML Portfolio Gallery

it uses xml and html both for images and tabs i tried to find option for description but 
could not find it on jQuery XML Portfolio Gallery

http://pexeto.com/tonic_gallery/index2.html
i need category description below each tab
for example tab1 info below tab1 ,tab2 info below tab2

is this possible with this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's not a native functionality, but you should be able to use HTML as category names. In your XML file, try adding the description directly in the name field:

```
<category id="tab1"><![CDATA[
    tab1
    <br />
    info below tab1
]]></category>
```

Note that this will break the design as it's not meant to be used this way, so you would have to update the styles to match your new design in the CSS file.